# How to enable user to drop event freely between allDay and non allDay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to enable user to drop the event freely either to allDay to hasTime day or from hasTime day to allDay.

I have this block of code for eventDrop.

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view, dayDelta, minuteDelta, calEvent, allDay, start, end) {
                var cCheck = event.start.toJSON().slice(0,10);
                var cToday = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
                if(cCheck < cToday){
                    revertFunc();
                    alert("You are FORBIDED to drop an event on past dates");
                }
                else{
                    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to move " + event.title + " to this date "+JSON.stringify(event.start)+" ?")) {
                        revertFunc();
                        //self.$el.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                        console.log(event);
                    } else {


                            var deltaId = event.id;
                            var deltaStart = event.start;
                            var deltaEnd = event.end;
                            var dropDelta = JSON.parse(localStorage["events"]);
                            for (var i = 0; i < dropDelta.length; i++) {
                                if(dropDelta[i].id == deltaId){
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(dropDelta[i].id)+"<<<>>>"+deltaId);
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(dropDelta[i].start)+"<<<>>>"+deltaStart);
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(dropDelta[i].end)+"<<<>>>"+deltaEnd);                                      
                                    dropDelta[i].start = deltaStart;
                                    // This is where complicated begins
                                    if(dropDelta[i].allDay == true){
                                        if(deltaEnd == null){
                                            dropDelta[i].allDay == false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            dropDelta[i].end = deltaEnd;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if(deltaEnd == null){
                                            //something happen
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            //something happen
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }   
                            localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(dropDelta));
                            alert("Successful");


                    }
                }
            },
```

I am having trouble on if statement. I am not sure how to make it logic. The more i think of it, the more confused i become.@_@

And here is my create new event code. Maybe this will help you guys understand more about my problem.

```
select: function (start, end, allDay, event ) {
                var cCheck = start._d.toJSON().slice(0,10);
                var cToday = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
                if(cCheck < cToday){
                    alert("You are FORBIDED to create event on past dates");
                }
                else{
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var index=localStorage.getItem("MaxIndex");
                    var eventData = [];
                    if (title) {
                        eventData = {
                            id: 'ef'+index++,
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            //allDay: true,
                        }
                        alert(eventData);
                        self.$el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                        events.push(eventData);
                        alert(eventData);
                        localStorage.setItem('MaxIndex', index);
                        localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));
                        self.$el.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventData );
                        self.$el.fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventData );
                        console.log(eventData);
                    }
                }
                self.$el.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
```

**additional note:**

I use `if(deltaEnd == null)` is because everytime i drop the event from allDay to non allDay, the end date become null. Forgot to mention, i am using fullCalendar.